# How to copy the same list to another entity

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I need to copy a existent list to another entities, but when the entity framework save only one entity persit the list.

```
var myList = GetList();

var newList = myEntities.Select(x =>
{
   var entity = x.GetEntity();

   entity.List = myList.ToList();

   return entity;
}).ToList()

Repository.SaveMany(newList);
Repository.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Well of course, although `myList.ToList()` does create a new list, the items in it aren't copied, so the last `entity` receiving them wins. By the way, it is bad practice to execute `Select` with side effects. Use `myEntities.ToList().ForEach(...)`.

Comment: @GertArnold , thank you so much, I really did this, but I was in doubt about this behavior.

I understood, this make sense now, I thinked that object in the list will copied too..